# How do I make a table centered

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, html-table

This is what I have below I just need to make the table centered. How do I make the table centered? For the site I'm using bootstrap CSS3 and HTML5

This is the entire section - the rest of it is ok and is working good, I'm just having an issue with the table. I cannot get it centered:

```
<section id="international" class="international">

<div class="section-heading">
<h6 class="title wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay=".3s"> Available     Internationally</h6>



<p class="wow fadeInDown" data-wow-delay=".5s">
<div class="para">

        test text

<br>


<style type="text/css">

.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;border:none;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:1px 10px;border-style:solid;border-width:0px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg th{font-family:roboto, sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:normal;padding:1px 10px;border-style:solid;border-width:0px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg .tg-yfiy{font-weight:bold;font-size:16px;vertical-align:bottom}
.tg .tg-qv16{font-weight:bold;font-size:16px;text-align:center;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-k010{font-weight:bold;font-size:16px;text-align:center;vertical-align:bottom}
.tg .tg-yw4l{vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-qnmb{font-weight:bold;font-size:16px;text-align:center}

</style>

<table align="center" class="tg" style="undefined;table-layout: fixed; width: 563px">

<colgroup>
<col style="width: 166px">
<col style="width: 81px">
<col style="width: 79px">
<col style="width: 86px">
<col style="width: 85px">
<col style="width: 66px">
</colgroup>
<tr>
<th class="tg-yfiy">test</th>
<th class="tg-k010">one</th>
<th class="tg-qv16">two</th>
<th class="tg-qv16">three</th>
<th class="tg-qv16">four</th>
<th class="tg-qv16">five</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
<td class="tg-qnmb">one</td>
<td class="tg-qv16">two</td>
<td class="tg-qv16">three</td>
<td class="tg-qv16">four</td>
<td class="tg-qv16">five</td>
</tr>
</table>  


</div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: My go-to for centering: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Comment: Use this command in table tag to get it centered:-

style="text-align:center"

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this on mine, seems to be [centered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sX24.jpg). You can try: `margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto` for horizontal alignment;
`margin-top:auto; margin-bottom:auto`, for vertical alignment or
`margin:auto` for both.

Comment: Thanks guys. Can't believe I forgot the margin.. this worked margin: 0 auto;

Comment: My apologies, first time on here. How do I mark it as answered?

Comment: @Classics07 There's a checkmark outline underneath where you vote, click it and it will turn green to mark as correct. ;)